# How to call multiple event handlers on one div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I've got an icon that shows a popup div when the user hovers over it or focuses on it and then disappears when the users mouse moves out or blur.
Currently I have this:

```
<div
  className="iconWrapper"
  onFocus={() => this.showToolTip(true)}
  onBlur={() => this.showToolTip(false)}
  onMouseOver={() => this.showToolTip(true)}
  onMouseOut={() => this.showToolTip(false)}
  tabIndex="0"
  role="button">
    <Icon width="12" height="12" fillColor="#000" />
  </div>
```

This works but its pretty messy, is there another way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you want to memoize.

If you don't want to memoize at all, you can at least avoid creating multiple identical functions:

```
const showToolTip = () => this.showToolTip(true);
const hideToolTip = () => this.showToolTip(false);
return (
    <div
        className="iconWrapper"
        onFocus={showToolTip}
        onBlur={hideToolTip}
        onMouseOver={showToolTip}
        onMouseOut={hideToolTip}
        tabIndex="0"
        role="button"
    >
        <Icon width="12" height="12" fillColor="#000" />
    </div>
);
```

Or you could create those functions once in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ***NOTE** I renamed your original instance method from `showToolTip` to
    // `updateToolTip` so I could use `showToolTip` for the one that specifically
    // *shows* it
    this.showToolTip = () => this.updateToolTip(true);
    this.hideToolTip = () => this.updateToolTip(false);
}
```

...then reuse those across renders:

```
return (
    <div
        className="iconWrapper"
        onFocus={this.showToolTip}
        onBlur={this.hideToolTip}
        onMouseOver={this.showToolTip}
        onMouseOut={this.hideToolTip}
        tabIndex="0"
        role="button"
    >
        <Icon width="12" height="12" fillColor="#000" />
    </div>
);
```

That has the advantage that it makes your event handler functions *stable* across renders. It doesn't matter much for a `div`, but if you were providing those functions to a `class` component using `shouldComponentUpdate` or a function component using `React.memo` to optimize rendering, having them be stable could save the child component renders.

Comment: Thanks T.J Crowder, I'll keep this Q open for a little while to see what else I could do but if nothing else comes I'll set this as the answer, it's a nice optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option what comes in my mind is to create `handlers` object and use spread syntax on component:

```
const toolTipHandlers = { 
                   onFocus: () => this.showToolTip(true),
                   onBlur: () => this.showToolTip(false),
                   onMouseOver: () => this.showToolTip(true),
                   onMouseOut: () => this.showToolTip(false),
                  };
return(
    <div
        {...toolTipHandlers}
        className="iconWrapper"
        tabIndex="0"
        role="button"
    >
    <Icon width="12" height="12" fillColor="#000" />
  </div>);
```